# How to clone a ucontext

Tags: c, linux, unix, ucontext

I wonder how to clone a ucontext. Note: this is different from `getcontext` and `swapcontext`, because I would like to have a `fork(2)`-like behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried double swapping to duplicate user context, but indeed the underlying stack is stayed unchanged and is problematic.

Comment: ask yourself, what would happen, if you copied a stack?

Comment: sorry I am not getting your point...

Comment: Look at the `clone` syscall. You can specify a stack address for the child thread. You may need to do something similar.

Comment: Or, look at GNU portable threads: https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/ and see how they do it

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, I will take a look. Now I am copying the `uc_stack` and `REG_RSP` of `uc_mcontext` but receiving a segfault.